# Out of different set of dates I want to check if all set of dates are contiguous

Tags: python, date

if I have 2 different set of dates:

```
01/05/2022 - 31/12/2022
01/01/2023 - 31/12/2023

01/05/2022 - 30/09/2022
01/10/2022 - 31/12/2022
01/01/2023 - 31/12/2023
```

I want to check if both set of dates above are contiguous between below range of dates

```
Date 1 = 01/05/2022
Date 2 = 31/12/2023
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me easier to use pandas to check if dates fall into the date range.
You have the data day, month, year. In my practice, I usually see the sequences year, month, day.
I changed the variables 'Date_1', 'Date_2' to the desired format and the arrays themselves with dates, which I divided into two parts from and to. Then I filled the dataframe with these arrays and checked the date range. I specifically added one line with data for clarity: 2023-01-01 2025-12-31, it is just filtered, since it does not fall under the condition.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

Date_1 = '01/05/2022'
Date_2 = '31/12/2023'
Date_1 = datetime.strptime(Date_1, "%d/%m/%Y")
Date_2 = datetime.strptime(Date_2, "%d/%m/%Y")
start = [datetime.strptime(i, "%d/%m/%Y")for i in ['01/05/2022', '01/01/2023', '01/05/2022', '01/10/2022', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023']]
finish = [datetime.strptime(i, "%d/%m/%Y")for i in ['31/12/2022', '31/12/2023', '30/09/2022', '31/12/2022', '31/12/2023', '31/12/2025']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': start, 'finish': finish})
print(df)
print(df[(df['start'] >= Date_1) & (df['finish'] <= Date_2)])
```

Output print(df)

```
       start     finish
0 2022-05-01 2022-12-31
1 2023-01-01 2023-12-31
2 2022-05-01 2022-09-30
3 2022-10-01 2022-12-31
4 2023-01-01 2023-12-31
5 2023-01-01 2025-12-31
```

Output print(df[(df['start'] >= Date_1) & (df['finish'] <= Date_2)])

```
       start     finish
0 2022-05-01 2022-12-31
1 2023-01-01 2023-12-31
2 2022-05-01 2022-09-30
3 2022-10-01 2022-12-31
4 2023-01-01 2023-12-31
```